# How to calculate sweep time of FMCW radar?

Tags: radar, sweep

I am designing a FMCW radar with center frequency 24GHz and sweep bandwidth of 150 MHz. How do I decide on the sweep time of the FMCW radar?

Comment: well, what are the other requirements of your radar system?

Comment: Which parameters should be taken into consideration while deciding on the sweep time?

Answer (score 3):

*As for this question 2 months have been passed but it would be helpful for the users looking for the relevant information,*

There are couple of factors which are related to the sweep time,

- Maximum velocity after successive chirp Fourier transform.
- The sweep time should be at least 10 to 20 times the maximum round trip time to have enough samples also from the range near maximum allowed range.

There is an excellent document here [FMCW Signal Processing](http://www.codar.com/images/about/1990LipaBarr_FMCW.pdf)